# Why expression is not working in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Work on EF,Need to write a custom where

```
public virtual IEnumerable GetDataByID<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    if (this.Context == null)
        Initialize<TEntity>();
    TContext context = this.Context;

    var result = context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().Where(GetExpression<TEntity>(5));
    return result;
}

public Expression GetExpression<TEntity>(int id) where TEntity : class
{
    ParameterExpression e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
    PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(EntityInfo<TEntity>.GetPkFieldName(this.Context));//(KeyPropertyName);
    MemberExpression m = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(e, propInfo);
    ConstantExpression c = Expression.Constant(id, typeof(int));
    BinaryExpression b = Expression.Equal(m, c);
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(b, e);
    return lambda;
}
```

Error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.Where(string, params
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' has some invalid arguments

Why my above syntax is not working, how to fix it?

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.Where(string, params
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' has some invalid arguments

The problem is this line:

```
var result = context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().Where(GetExpression<TEntity>(5));
```

Infact you're specifing the wrong parameters: [`ObjectQuery<T>.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx)

```
public ObjectQuery<T> Where(
    string predicate,
    params ObjectParameter[] parameters
)
```

Infact you should pass a string.

Comment: I clicked to downvote before your edit, where you were comparing an entity to an expression. SO seems to have registered the downvote as occurring after the edit (minor glitch?) so I am currently unable to remove it. If you make a small edit I will remove the downvote, as I see nothing wrong with the answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the result of `CreateObjectSet<TEntity>` returns an `ObjectSet<TEntity>` which defines its own [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx) method which the compiler will attempt to use. The arguments you are providing are not valid for this method, hence the error.

What you want to be using is Linq's [`Queryable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) extension method like so:

```
var predicate = GetExpression<TEntity>(5);
var objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
var results = System.Linq.Queryable.Where(objectSet, predicate);
```